# trouble with short Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have this short makefile. UNAME is coming from uname command, but for purposes of example, its just hardcoded. I'd like to check that if UNAME starts with string "MINGW32_NT", then code inside if should execute.

```
UNAME := Linux  # MINGW32_NT-6.1

ifneq ( $(findstr MINGW32_NT, $(UNAME)) , "" )  
      UNAME := MINGW32
endif


info:   
      @echo Compiling for "$(UNAME)"
```

**EDIT: THe problem was the quotes and spaces. ;-)**

```
ifneq ($(findstring MINGW32_NT, $(UNAME)),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using GNU make, the function should be `findstring`.

Also, rules for strings and spaces are a little strict in `Makefile`. The following works:

```
UNAME := Linux  # MINGW32_NT-6.1

ifneq ($(findstring MINGW32_NT,$(UNAME)),)  
      UNAME := MINGW32
endif


info:   
      @echo Compiling for "$(UNAME)"
```

(note that I removed all the spurious spaces in the `ifneq` test.)